# Error import file json

Tags: json, import, rethinkdb

I'm trying to import a `rethinkdb` *json file* and I get the following error:

> "Out of range values are not JSON float compliant"

How  can I fix it?

Comment: Do you have extremely large floats somewhere in your data? I would try splitting up the file to try and identify where the problem object is.

Comment: Hey Christian, just checking in again. Did you fix your problem?